# Fixing Spray Paint Texture

Tags: paint, spraypainting

I am working on a project and spray painting smooth composite wood pieces with a glossy paint/primer combo ([specifically this](http://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/painters-touch-ultra-cover-2x/gloss)).  I sprayed outside (at night) and there was a slight breeze.  For the most part, the texture is glossy as it should be but, some areas have a slight texture to them (likely due to improper coverage).

My question is, what is the best way to fix these areas.  Should I spray another layer of paint over them?  Should I sand them down with fine sandpaper?  I've done some Googling but, I've been unable to locate a solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sand evenly across the entire board to make it smooth.  Clean and remove all dust from sanding.  Respray as evenly as possible.  If you can get away with doing it indoors (a garage for example) that is recommended to reduce the number of airborne particles that land in the paint before it can dry.

To ensure an even coat my personal method is to gauge the coverage by sheen rather than color.  Meaning that if you view it at an angle the wet portions will be shinier than the less covered portions.  Color can be deceiving, look at the sheen, if the sheen matches (as you spray) across the piece, the final product will be more even as well.

Keep in mind that with spray paint it takes less time to do extra coats of paint than it does to put on too much and fix a poor result...tempting though it may be to try.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Spraying Too Much Paint

Spraying the “right” amount of paint is critical. Spraying too much paint can produce an orange peel texture on the surface of our projects. Makayla recommends adjusting the “volume control knob to make sure you aren't outputting too much paint.”

Comment: This is an 8 year old question, not that late answers are automatically bad. However, the OP specified he was using _cans_ of paint, and I've never seen a can that had any sort of "volume control know". Also, who is "Makayla" that makes this recommendation?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).